# Explicitly acquire EXCLUSIVE LOCK on a SEQUENCE OBJECT

Tags: sql-server-2012, sequence

How can we explicitly acquire a exclusive lock on a Sequence object in SQL Server 2012?

I am creating an application and need to lock a sequence object so no other transaction fetch data from it.

Can we achieve this by using get_applock procedure?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: @JohnM My application when ever I need to advance my sequence I am restarting it with currentvalue+Delta value, but it is showing some weird outputs sometime. SO to avoid discrepancies in data

Comment: If you can post the SQL you're using for this it may help. I don't believe you can lock a sequence object so some other method will have to do, but I'm not sure I understand your use case yet.